Swale puddles/floods before driveway - looking for solution
I'm in an area of occasional hurricanes and heavy rains in South Florida.  In the images you can see the swale with some gravel right before the driveway to the house.  This section gets flooded up to the level of the sidewalk.
What solves this?  If I add more gravel or stones of some kind, then how do I shape/curve the edges to keep the gravel confined to that area as I drive across it?  Is there some standard curve to follow?  How to define the edges?



What you are looking to do is defeat the purpose of the swale.
Since there are no storm sewers, rain water is directed off the road surface to the side of the road and then toward the nearest Drainage Retention Area.
Changing the swale disrupts the flow of water to the DRA. The county you reside in is usually responsible for ground water management.  You can give the county public work department a call and describe your issue. They may be willing to adjust the whole side of the street, or may tell you tough luck.
What you are experiancing is the common way to divert rain water in most of Florida.  The good thing is our soil, being so sandy, usually absorbs the rain rather quickly.  Having swales full of water right after a hard rain is the bad part of Florida life. That they empty in about 5 minutes is one of the good things.

I understand now.  I thought to improve the appearance in the process.

Sounds to me like the OP is talking about the depression in the ground in front of the driveway—where you can see the rutting.  IMO this is the result of not having a concrete apron there.  The vehicles drive over the dirt area and compact the soil, creating that depression.

@Huesmann, Yes ,you are correct. The area is compacted from driving over it. That is also why grass does not grow well. The depression is designed to collect and guide water.  Even if you get permission to pave the area for your driveway it must dip to at least 15 inches below the crown of the road before rising to complete the driveway.  This is just common for ground water control in many areas of Fla.

First let me say that the part between the road and the sidewalk looks a bit too shallow/flat to be a "proper" swale (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swale_%28landform%29). For that it would have to be a bit deeper so water can run into it and accumulate. Maybe it is enough for your area (I am not from Florida or even the US) though.
Regarding the question: if you are allowed to modify that part of the road/sidewalk area at all (depends on you local regulations/code), you definitely want to maintain the draining properties as mentioned in the other answer, otherwise you risk flooding your (or neighbors) property or the street.
One option to achieve that would be to install some kind of permeable paving, for example:

(source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Rasenpflasterstein_1.jpg)
Another, possibly cheaper option would be to install a permeable gravel "driveway" with stabilization mats underneath, for example:

(source: https://www.greendriveway.com/products/gd-gravel/, no affiliation or recommendation, just happens to be the first search result)
Again, you may not be allowed to do any of this, but these would be options to consider for a situation like this.

It does look very shallow to the naked eye, but believe me the contour does dip enough to collect and control water.   The counties try to have a nice compromise between a dip for water and nothing that hampers driving a car into the driveway.  When it rains hard those areas do collect the water.

I aggree that it does not appear to be a swale, but I guess it's Florida.  I'm in Utah, we have irrigation water that runs in the gutters in many towns - unique to this region.  Drive ways cross these area with small bridges - Don't know if this would be legal there.  They are really just concrete slabs that sit on (they are strongly attached to the slab) other concrete slabs that hold it up,  Most of the area under the slab allows free-flow of water. Sometimes these 'bridges' are metal or partly so.

@EricDeloak Yeah, we've always called them swales, but you're right, they're not very trough-like.  It actually had never occurred to me, I'm ashamed to admit, after all these years, what their function was until RMDman pointed it out.  Also, the flood zone maps here are scaled 1 to 5 with Zone 1 having the highest chance of flooding/evacuation and Zone 5 the lowest chance.  I'm in Zone 5.
